# Fullcalendar to pass previous and next month value in event calendar using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I need to pass the previous and next month value using ajax url to get the events data by monthly wise, I have tried but am not getting the relevant output, here by clicking previous and next button to get the month value from this div $('div.fc-center').text() and to fetch those value by month_year input id, in events ineed to pass the month_year value to the load_events page the to get the data as selected month.

```
   $(".fc-next-button").click(function()
        {
        alert("next");
        var temp1 = $('div.fc-center').text();
        alert(temp1);
        $('#month_year').val(temp1);

        });     
    $('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today', 
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month'
        },


        defaultDate: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        showNonCurrentDates: false,


    events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ) {

     $.ajax({
              url: 'load_events.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: {
                  start: start.unix(),
                  end: end.unix(),
                  month_year: $('#month_year').val(),
                  var cu_date =  new Date($('#calendar1').fullCalendar('getDate')),
                  var  month_integer = date.getMonth(),
                  var  year_integer = date.getFullYear(),
              },
              success: function(doc) {
                console.log(doc);
                  var events = [];
                  $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                      events.push({
                          title: $(this).attr('title'),
                          start: $(this).attr('start')
                      });
                       $("#calendar1").fullCalendar("rerenderEvents");
                  });

              callback(doc);

              }
        });



  },

   });
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
include('../config.php'); 
$start = $_GET['start']; 
$start_dd = date('Y-m-d',$start); 
$end = $_GET['end']; 
$end_dd = date('Y-m-d',$end); 
$data = array(); 
$data[] = array( 
  'id' => 1, 'title' => date('Y-m-d').'-'.$start_dd.'-'.$end_dd, 
  'start' => date('Y-m-d'), 
  'end' => date('Y-m-d'), 
); 
echo json_encode($data); 
?>
```

output: in current month it shows the output like this

> start.unix() - >29.04.2018 and end.unix - > 10.06.2018

Comment: " ineed to pass the month_year value to the load_events page"...no you don't because you're already passing `start` and `end` values which describe the date range the server should send events for. The server can read from these values and send the appropriate data. This is more flexible than sending just a month/year value, as it allows for views of different lengths (e.g. week view). It's also nice because fullCalendar already gives you this info in the `events` function, so you don't have to do any extra work to fetch it.

Comment: BTW all of this code: `var events = [];
                  $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                      events.push({
                          title: $(this).attr('title'),
                          start: $(this).attr('start')
                      });
                       $("#calendar1").fullCalendar("rerenderEvents");
                  });` appears to be unnecessary, because at the end of the function you simply do `callback(doc)` which sends the original result from the server back to fullCalendar. The rest of it achieves nothing.

Comment: And lastly your `$(".fc-next-button").click(function()` will never work anyway because you've written it before you create the calendar, so the button you're trying to attach the event to doesn't exist yet, because fullCalendar hasn't created it yet. Therefore the event will be attached to nothing. However like I explained, it doesn't matter because you don't need this function anyway.

Comment: without passing the date it shows wrong date (ie), when i clicking next and previous button, in ajax  i have passed  start: start.unix(),
                      end: end.unix(), these two date, in calendar am getting wrong date, pls do my needs.

Comment: "in calendar I am getting wrong date"...you mean the wrong date is displayed on the screen, or the events returned are for the wrong dates? Please give an example. If you don't interfere with those next/previous buttons they should work correctly automatically.

Comment: what does it means? start: start.unix(), end: end.unix(), what is the output date of these two dates,  also i have attached load_events.php code,pls refer my code and do my needs,

Comment: <?php

include('../config.php'); 
 
 $start = $_GET['start'];
 $start_dd = date('Y-m-d',$start);
 $end = $_GET['end'];
 $end_dd = date('Y-m-d',$end);
 
 $data = array();
 $data[] = array(
   'id'   =>  1,
   'title'   =>  date('Y-m-d').'-'.$start_dd.'-'.$end_dd,
   'start'   =>  date('Y-m-d'),
   'end'   =>  date('Y-m-d'),
 );
 
 echo json_encode($data);
 ?>   output: in current month it shows the output like this start.unix() - >29.04.2018 and end.unix - > 10.06.2018

Comment: if that's the output then your code is correct. Those are the start and end dates of a typical "month" layout in fullCalendar - e.g. look at the dates in the example on the front page of the site: https://fullcalendar.io/ . There are a few days before the month start and a few days after the end, just to fill the grid neatly. I'm unsure what you believe the issue is? What did you expect to happen?